# Need clarification on addObjectsFromArray function

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have the following code (both items and itemsCopy are NSMutableArray's):

```
//DO: populate items w/ 30 elements
[self.itemsCopy addObjectsFromArray:self.items];
//DO: remove all elements in items
```

Results

```
Begin Pass 1:
itemsCopy = 0
items = 30

End Pass 1:
itemsCopy = 30
items = 0

Begin Pass 2:
itemsCopy = 0
items = 30

End Pass 2:
itemsCopy = 30
items = 0
```

How can I constantly append items to the end of itemsCopy? I would like the scenario to look like this:

```
Begin Pass 1:
itemsCopy = 0
items = 30

End Pass 1:
itemsCopy = 30;
items = 0;

Begin Pass 2:
itemsCopy = 30
items = 30

End Pass 2:
itemsCopy = 60
items = 0
```

Comment: somewhere you must be re-initializing the itemsCopy array, or on each pass performing the operation on a different object....

Comment: so addObjectsFromArray should always append?

Comment: Sheehan Alam: Yes. See the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/addObjectsFromArray: Nowhere does it say that it will ever reset the array, nor is there any reason why it would.

Answer (score 3):

By keeping the same array you just filled in the `itemsCopy` property. It's clearly being reset to an empty array with whatever method you're using.